# Outlook team calendar in overlay mode

Tags: outlook, groups, calendar

Scenario:

We are 4 employees in a team and are using outlook for emails and calendar.
We as a team want to be able to have one single calendar view that displays:
- the events where our whole team is invited/needed
- our own events
- the events of our teammates

The problem is, that it should NOT display duplicated events.
Currently i have all the 2 other calendars of my teammates in overlay mode merged into my calendar-view.
But, if our team (we all 4) get invited to activity A, then we all 4 accept this activity and so in my calendar activity A is now existing 4 times. This leads (in the week-view) to me not beeing able to read anything from the title, because the label is just so narrow...
If you don't understand what i am talking about, look at this example image [here](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/chap5_9780735660045/elementLinks/httpatomoreillycomsourcemspimages912876.png) and image one activity 4 (or even 5) times next to each other.

I searched for days but wasn't able to find a solution.
My closest solution was to create a new calendar in my account, name it "team", share it with everyone and use this calendar for team-activities. But this also doesn't work well, because nobody can "invite" this calendar.

Does anybody have a solution for this? :/

PS: I hope serverfault is the closest stack exchange area for this topic. If not, please be so kind and tell me, where is hould ask this instead. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The duplicated events which you encountered were like the following snapshot, right?
 [image]

If so, I just tried to create a new meeting for three mailboxes **Test**, **T1** and **T2**, and then merge their calendars as you did, after that, the result was also like the above snapshot. It seems that the duplicated events are displayed after merging calendars by design.

> > My closest solution was to create a new calendar in my account, name it "team", share it with everyone and use this calendar for team-activities. But this also doesn't work well, because nobody can "invite" this calendar.

As you said, you could create a new calendar **Teams** in your account to launch meeting invites. At the same time, if you want to enable other users to “invite” your calendar, you should grant permissions to these users. You could perform the following steps to grant permissions:

1. Right-click your calendar **Teams** and click **Properties**:

   [image]
2. Add your users’ mailboxes:

[image]

3. Grant permissions to them
   (More details about the roles of these permission levels: [What Do The Outlook Permission Levels Mean?](https://kb.intermedia.net/Article/1214)):

[image]

Comment: 1. Yes, your example is exactly what i'm talking about.
2. There was a problem with the team-calendar approach that i just don't remember to 100%. I think it was related to other people not beeing able to see if i'm available when they want to invite me (our exchange outlook previews availability when creating an event) because this team-calendar is not my "primary" calendar and i cannot set it as this (even if I could, my teammtes for sure cannot). Will investigate again and write back nest days.

Comment: Are there any updates? If so, I look forward to your good results. :)

Comment: Hey Ivan :) So: Availability (when trying to invite some team-member) is not working with the shared-calendar method, from what i saw. Also, nobody can invite my team/shared calendar (because it's no person, just a calendar). I will further test, if at least people, who add my shared calendar, get reminders for upcoming events and stuff like that.It's still a bad solution. I would think that a company as microsoft (!) would be able to have something easy and needed as a "team-calendar". If you have any more idea or information on this topic,please comment here.Appreciate every piece of info :/